# Customizing Amazon's Crowd HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

I have a task where turkers should annotate elements with bounding boxes, with the added extension of being able to connect two boxes with each other (to indicate a relationship, like with an arrow).

This is obviously really close to their [crowd-bounding-box](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-crowd-bounding-box.html) element, but I don't see a way of extending the underlying functionality with my feature.

Do I really have to re-implement the whole interface or is there source code available for their crowd elements?

Comment: if you find the answer to this, I'd be interested.

Comment: @Daniel I haven't found a way to do it, but check my comment for an alternative open-source implementation

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a way to extend the code from Amazon, I built my own annotation front-end and open-sourced it: https://github.com/Dzeri96/sci-annot.

Check it out if you're in need of something similar.